# listing recordset grouped alphabetically

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp-classic

i'm creating a hebrew glossary page for a client using ASP and MySQL.
i want to create a recordset and then loop through the results, grouping by the first letter and each with its own heading... something like this :

A
Apple
Avacado
Ape

B
Bilge
beetle

etcetc

can anyone suggest a good way of doing this?
i did find a jquery plugin which would be perfect (and automatic) : http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx
the only problem i had is that it doesn't work at all for hebrew characters.

so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to group your data, just loop through it this way. Adjust to suit your database fields accordingly:

```
<%
set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open "Select * FROM myTable order by Term asc",conn,3,3
lastLetter = "" 

do while not RS.eof
        firstLetter = left(RS("Term"),1)
        if lastLetter <> firstLetter then
            response.write("<b>" & firstLetter & "</b><br />"
        end if
        resonse.write(RS("Term")&"<br />"
        lastLetter = firstLetter
RS.movenext
loop
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar. I don't know ASP but in PHP I used a simple array like so

```
$r = mysql_query( ' select * from table ' );

$array = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $r ) ) {

  $array[strtolower(substr($row['name'],0,1))][] = $row;

}
```

This creates an array with nested arrays. The key of the highest array is the first letter of the name column. Then each one of those has a nested array with the row.

You can no doubt do the same in ASP.